# I am trying to integrate a calendar called fullcalendar in symfony 5

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, xmlhttprequest, fullcalendar

I am trying to integrate [fullCalendarJS](https://fullcalendar.io/) in symfony5.4 and for this I am watching a [video](https://youtu.be/HaTN0_S-rew?t=3087) which right in that part the HTTP server It responds perfectly, however doing something similar tells me that in the line that comes out this code `xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));` It tells me that data is incomplete and gives me an HTTP 404 error that the page cannot be found.

From what I've seen, it can be done with Fetch and in fact it's more formal and more comfortable, but I don't know how to implement it in code. So I leave you my code in case someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CalendarRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CalendarRepository::class)]
class Calendar
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $title = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $start = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::DATETIME_MUTABLE)]
    private ?\DateTimeInterface $end = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $description = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?bool $all_day = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 12)]
    private ?string $background_color = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 12)]
    private ?string $border_color = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 12)]
    private ?string $text_color = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStart(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->start;
    }

    public function setStart(\DateTimeInterface $start): self
    {
        $this->start = $start;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEnd(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->end;
    }

    public function setEnd(\DateTimeInterface $end): self
    {
        $this->end = $end;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function isAllDay(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->all_day;
    }

    public function setAllDay(bool $all_day): self
    {
        $this->all_day = $all_day;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBackgroundColor(): ?string
    {
        return $this->background_color;
    }

    public function setBackgroundColor(string $background_color): self
    {
        $this->background_color = $background_color;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBorderColor(): ?string
    {
        return $this->border_color;
    }

    public function setBorderColor(string $border_color): self
    {
        $this->border_color = $border_color;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTextColor(): ?string
    {
        return $this->text_color;
    }

    public function setTextColor(string $text_color): self
    {
        $this->text_color = $text_color;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My function where I want the calendar to appear

```
#[Route('/', name: 'main')]
    public function index(CalendarRepository $calendar): Response
    {
        $events = $calendar->findAll();
        $rdvs = [];
        foreach($events as $event){
            $rdvs[] = [
                'id' => $event->getId(),
                'start' => $event->getStart()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'end' => $event->getEnd()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                'title' => $event->getTitle(),
                'description' => $event->getDescription(),
                'backgroundColor' => $event->getBackgroundColor(),
                'borderColor' => $event->getBorderColor(),
                'textColor' => $event->getTextColor(),
                'allDay' => $event->isAllDay(),
            ];
        }
        $data = $this->json($rdvs);
        return $this->render('main/index.html.twig',['data' => $data->getContent()]);

        // return new Response('',404);
    }
```

ApiController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Calendar;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class ApiController extends AbstractController
{
    // #[Route('/api', name: 'app_api')]
    // public function index(): Response
    // {
    //     return $this->render('api/index.html.twig', [
    //         'controller_name' => 'ApiController',
    //     ]);
    // }

    #[Route('/api/{id}/edit', name: 'api_event_edit', methods:'PUT')]
    public function majEvent(?Calendar $calendar,Request $request,ManagerRegistry $doctrine): Response
    {

        $data = $this->json($request->getContent());

        if (isset($data->title) && !empty($data->title) &&
            isset($data->start) && !empty($data->start) &&
            isset($data->description) && !empty($data->description) &&
            isset($data->backgroundColor) && !empty($data->backgroundColor) &&
            isset($data->borderColor) && !empty($data->borderColor) &&
            isset($data->textColor) && !empty($data->textColor))
            {
                $code = 200;

                if (!$calendar) {
                    $calendar = new Calendar();
                    $code = 201;
                }

                $calendar->setTitle($data->title);
                $calendar->setStart(new DateTime($data->start));
                $calendar->setDescription($data->description);
                if ($data->allDay) {
                    $calendar->setEnd(new DateTime($data->start));
                }else{
                    $calendar->setEnd(new DateTime($data->end));
                }
                $calendar->setAllDay($data->allDay);
                $calendar->setBackgroundColor($data->backgroundColor);
                $calendar->setBorderColor($data->borderColor);
                $calendar->setTextColor($data->textColor);

                $em = $doctrine->getManager();
                $em->persist($calendar);
                $em->flush();

                return new Response('Ok',$code);
            }else{
                return new Response('Datos incompletos',404);
            }

        return $this->render('api/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'ApiController',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And this is my twig with a script

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Hello MainController!{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<div id="calendrier">
</div>

{# <div id="mainbodyBlock">
    <div id="cardmain1" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="{{path('familia')}}">
            <img src="/img/reloj.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Familia</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="cardmain2" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <a href="{{path('plantilla')}}">
            <img src="/img/calendario.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p class="card-text">Plantilla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> #}

{% endblock %}


{% block javascripts %}
    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
            let calendarElt = document.querySelector("#calendrier")

            let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarElt, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                locale: 'es',
                timeZone: 'Europe/Madrid',
                headerToolbar: {
                    start: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    end: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
                },
                events: {{data|raw}},
                editable: true,
                eventResizableFromStart: true,
            })

            calendar.on('eventChange', (e) => {
                console.log(e);
                let url = `/api/${e.event.id}/edit`;

                let data = {
                    "title": e.event.title,
                    "description": e.event.extendedProps.description,
                    "start": e.event.start,
                    "end": e.event.end,
                    "backgroundColor": e.event.backgroundColor,
                    "borderColor": e.event.backgroundColor,
                    "textColor": e.event.textColor,
                    "allDay": e.event.allDay
                }

                let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

                xhr.open("PUT",url)
                xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            })

            calendar.render()
        }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

If they tell me a way to improve or optimize it, I will accept the advice and if the error is solved, all the better.

The objective is that each event is saved even if the day is changed and it is updated

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use fetch:

```js
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

const requestOptions = {
   method: 'PUT',
   headers: headers,
   body: JSON.stringify(data)
};
  
const req = fetch(url, requestOptions);
```

you can also wrap this code within an async function if needed

Comment: Indeed, when I change the event, it does not give an error, thank you very much! And to persist that data to the databases, how do I do it? With doctrine maybe? But how?

Comment: Which data are you talking about? because in your api controller there's persist and flush on calendar object (hydrated with data from request)

Comment: It's true I didn't remember then why don't you persist? If the data is supposed to be updated, right?

Comment: oh wait it gave me an error

He says ->

content-type: application/json
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36

and status I get N/A

Comment: If you'are using Symfony with AJAX, you should see the request in the debug toolbar. It's easier to find the problem. You could paste the error message?

Comment: In theory, it is the 404 error because the page cannot be found, but it should if I give it the data, right?

Comment: Mmm yes, your controller return `return new Response('Datos incompletos',404);`. Check your data. Maybe you could use Postman or Insomnia to test the API 

Comment: but it's a comment it shouldn't affect right?